# Contact form doesn't work - sending to contact.php "page"

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm learning PHP, and am trying to get a contact form into a website I'm working on. I've puzzled over this for a while, but my contact form does not work! I simply cannot understand what's the issue.

```
    <?php
$action=$_REQUEST['phpaction'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
    <form  action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="phpaction" value="submit">
    Your name:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your email:<br>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
        }
    else{        
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("sean@southernvoiceanddata.co.uk", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Email sent!";
        }
    }  
?>
```

Problem is, whenever I try to click "submit", it forwards me to the same page (www.website.com/contact). the URL is the same as the url of the contact page, but no email is sent, and the page throws out a 404.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

edit: ah, forgot to mention, I am using Wordpress on this site! I've been trying to slice through those issues as well, so I don't doubt they might be causing issues with the form. I'm not sure.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: The code is posted, in the jsfiddle link! Though, it throws up issues if I try to post the link directly. I'm not sure why. Whatever it wants me to do, there is no instruction whatsoever on /how/ to do it, and google's been less than useless in helping there. So, I've had to tinyurl it.

Comment: are you using the action attribute in your form?

Comment: honestly, I'm not sure. I'm fairly new to PHP, and what's there is all the code I have. I mean, it does have $action in there, so, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "name" parameter is reserved for/used by other wordpress purposes. If you rename it to "username" (for example) your script will probably work.

So, instead of `<input name="name" ..>`, use `<input name="username" ..>`, and get the variable with `$_POST['username']`.

Otherwise Wordpress will think you're looking for a post/page called whatever the user enters into the "name" field.. (hence the 404)

Comment: I see! well, what would I need to change? there's a lot of "action"s in that php. is it just the initial $action command? I'm still learning the ropes, so I'm not quite sure ^^;

Comment: You would have to replace it in two places:

- Where you read the variable: `$_REQUEST['action']` should be `$_REQUEST['phpaction']`

- Where you define your variable (in the form): `<input name="action" .. >` should be `<input name="phpaction" ..>`

Comment: I've done both of those, but it still 404's. I've updated the php in the topic. any ideas? :S

Comment: You're very right, I was mixed up. It's not "action" that's reserved but "name". I've edited my answer to give you the solution to your problem.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thanks a lot for your help! This fixed the issue completely! I had a feeling it was a wordpress issue. Well, the email sent, and is working properly now! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting providers do not support `mail()`. Make sure yours supports.

Comment: Ah, ok. I've fired off an email, and I'll see if they don't support it!